# Get Media Feature Pack

Tags: windows, windows-11

My Windows 11 PC does not contain Media Feature Pack. And I can't find it in Apps @ Features. How to get Media Feature Pack for my PC?

Winver:

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you have the Windows n version installed, it indeed does not come with Windows Media Player nor the Windows Media Feature Pack. This is always a separate download that you must install. I made that mistake before with Windows 8 and 10, thinking I didn't want the bloat, not realising that you also miss lots of codecs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research, it seems that the Windows Feature Pack is not available for Windows 11 Educational N version.

Microsoft used to have a separate download for windows 10 N versions, but switched to deliver this as an additional feature, which is missing in your operating system because it is the educational version of Windows 11.

Your only option is to upgrade your windows 11 to a license that includes Windows Feature Pack.

Comment: [Here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/media-feature-pack-for-windows-10-11-n-february-2023-2aaf89b8-f9d3-4322-98d0-612c9bea9c01) are the instructions, if the optional feature isn’t listed, then it cannot be enabled on Windows 11 Education. Reinstalling Windows 11 Home N on your system is one way to get an eligible edition installed on your system.

Answer (score 0):

Had same on Windows 10, but very probably is valid for Windows 11, run in PowerShell:

```
dism /online /add-capability /capabilityname:Media.MediaFeaturePack~~~~0.0.1.0
```

This was a rather unique way to install, since:

- None of [recommended](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/mediafeaturepack) packs for previous versions proceeded to install.
- In the same way, entry was missing in Windows Features.
- Multiple manually downloaded KB's refused to install.